# Display a deleted DataRow in a (Infragistics.Ultra-) grid

Tags: c#, wingrid

is it possible to display a DataRow from a DataTable which has the DataRowState.Deleted?

Scenario:
The user can edit some kind of lookup-informations which are presented in the grid.
Now he/she can delete, modify or insert multiple entries and finally store all his/her 
changes with one click to the database (assuming there is no primary-key-violation
or some other problem).

Now i want to colorize the different rows according to their edit-status, but the
deleted rows disappear immediatly.

Do you have any idea or another approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: I realized that the `Grid` you are using is not `DataGridView`. For anyone who wants to do the same with `DataGridView`, they can do the following:

1. Create a `DataView`:

   ```
   DataView myDataView = 
         new DataView(myDataTable, 
                      String.Empty,       // add a filter if you need one
                      "SortByColumn",
                      DataViewRowState.OriginalRows | DataViewRowState.Deleted); 

   myDataGridView.DataSource = myDataView;
   ```
2. Handle `UserAddedRow`, `UserDeletedRow` and `CellValueChanged` Events:

   ```
   private void myDataGridView_UserAddedRow
               (object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#CCFF99");
   }

   private void myDataGridView_UserDeletedRow
               (object sender, DataGridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       e.Row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFCC99");
   }

   private void myDataGridView_CellValueChanged
               (object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {
      myDataGridView[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor 
                                             = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FFFF99");
   }
   ```

Comment: @Vivek: thanks. The display-option for different DataRowStates in the DataView was exaclty what i was looking for.